# How can I use my PC's Internet connection with my Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I use Palm Treo 750 running Windows Mobile 6.1. I don't have GPRS on my mobile. However, I do have a broadband connection on my laptop running Windows Vista.

How can I use the PC's Internet connection to browse from mobile (either USB or Bluetooth)?

I have done this with one of my previous Windows mobiles (Smart Phone 2003 SE).

Answer (score 1):

You should install (update) ActiveSync on your laptop. And then it usually works automatic.
If not, use Start Menu, Settings, Connections (3rd Tab). I have a "USB to PC" icon there.

But the installed programs are configured by the Vendor, maybe yours are different. Describe how far you get. I would use USB (to start with).

Comment: Hi Henk, 

Thanks for the help. Your hint helped in finding out the solution.

This is what I did and now I am able to browse from the mobile. :)


In PC (Vista):

Open Windows Mobile Device Center
Mobile Device Settings > Connection Settings
Check "Allow USB connections"
This computer is connected to "Internet"

In Mobile

Open Connections > USB to PC
Either Check or clear the check box (Advanced...)